# Cannot find SKProduct from array by product identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am very new to IOS programming and come from a C# background so please bear with me!

As part of my attempt to add IAP to an app i'm working on I have to loop through the products returned in an SKProductsResponse to find the product which my customer has selected (since paymentWithProductIdentifier is deprecated).

In the following code I know that productSKU in my NSDictionary definately matches one of the product identifiers (at least, doing po in the console shows it to be the same...) but the if statement never runs. What have I done wrong? I've tried casting both sides to NSString with no success. Additionally, is there a better way to find the product from the productidentifier in the SKProductsResponse than by looping through?

```
SKProduct *product;
for (SKProduct *thisProduct in products) {
    if (thisProduct.productIdentifier == payload[@"productSKU"]) {
         product = thisProduct;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Chris

EDIT:

Ok, so I have found if I replace

```
if (thisProduct.productIdentifier == payload[@"productSKU"])
```

with

```
if ([thisProduct.productIdentifier isEqualToString:payload[@"productSKU"]])
```

it works. Can anyone explain why? I assume this is some sort of casting issue but I already tried

```
if ((NSString *)thisProduct.productIdentifier == (NSString *)payload[@"productSKU"])
```

with no success!

Comment: How are you setting the  value of products?

Comment: As I said in the question, products comes from a SKProductsResponse. I already know that products contains the right things because, as I said in the question, I can do a po on thisproduct.productIdentifier within the loop and see the correct identifier.

Comment: I should perhaps mention that products is an NSArray

Comment: Thanks, I should pay more attention to the question. If you have more than one SKProduct then unfortunately this is the quickest way. If you only have one product then use [response.product objectAtIndex:0]

Comment: The "==" compares pointers. The isEqualToString method compares the actual characters in the strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one SKProduct then unfortunately this is the quickest way. If you only have one product then use `[response.product objectAtIndex:0]`